# Update Span Element with Ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Hello again stack overflow

I have a simple PHP file (countsomething.php) that looks up a number and echo's it.

How do I get ajax to update a simple span element on my HTML page.

I've tried triggering the ajax on page load with : `<body class="skin-blue" onload="updateCDNonts();">`

The JS

```
function updateCDNonts() {
  $.get("x.x.x.x:8080/getliveontscdn.php=", function(result){
    $("#countonts").html(result)};
}
```

The HTML
       `<span id="countonts" class="info-box-number">0</span>`

Can someone point me in the right direction ?

Comment: You're missing a `)`.

Comment: You also have an extra `=` after `.php`.

Comment: If `x.x.x.x:8080` is not the same as the page URL, you'll probably get a CORS error in the console.

Comment: Are you getting errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: Console.log your js result variable to check where the problem comes from.

Comment: Hi, I have changed my code quite a bit including the php, and now parse the info as a json. 
the json looks like this 
`{"cdnonts":"144","eagonts":"0","stamonts":null,"foxonts":null,"pentonts":null,"topponts":null,"wickhamonts":null}`
and the js looks like this
    `<script language="javascript"> 
     window.onload = function() {
     alert("done");
     $.ajax({ 
     type: 'GET', 
     url: 'countallonts.php',
     dataType: "json",
     data: { get_param: 'cdnonts' }, 
     success: function(data){
       $('span#txthint').html( data.cdnonts );
     }});
    </script>`

Answer (score 0):

You have a few issues with your code i have tried to point them all out below for you:

```
function updateCDNonts() {
   $.get("x.x.x.x:8080/getliveontscdn.php", function(result){ //removed equals from url
   $("#countonts").html(result); //removed curly brace that shouldn't be there
 }); //added missing bracket and semicolon
```

Also as someone else noted watchout for cors if your url is different.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working. I changed my php script to return a json, here is the json: `{"cdnonts":"144","eagonts":"0","stamonts":null,"foxonts":null,"pentonts":null,"topponts":null,"wickhamonts":null}`

And in the html I did the following

```
            <script language="javascript">

                window.onload = function() {
                $.ajax({ 
                type: 'GET', 
                url: 'countallonts.php',
                dataType: "json",
                data: { get_param: 'cdnonts' },
                success: function(data){
                     $('span#cdnonts').html( data.cdnonts);
                     $('span#eagonts').html( data.eagonts);
                }});}

            </script>
```

Although I am not sure why it works, because I expected data variable to return just the "cdnonts" object, but I suspect it parses all of the objects instead?

Thank you for you help.

Comment: Just for info you dont need to use `js lang <script language="javascript">` just `<script>` is enough